# Every character in an array being recognized with ".hasOwnProperty(i)" in javascript as true with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script

This is the array:

```
{"C8_235550":
    {"listing":"aut,C8_235550_220144650654"},
"C8_231252":
    {"listing":"aut,C8_231252_220144650654"}}
```

It was fetched with a GET request from a Firebase database using Google Apps Script.

```
  var optList = {"method" : "get"};
  var rsltList = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://dbName.firebaseio.com/KeyName/.json", optList );
  var varUrList = rsltList.getContentText();
```

Notice the `.getContentText()` method.

I'm assuming that the array is now just a string of characters?  I don't know.
When I loop over the returned data, every single character is getting pushed, and the JavaScript code will not find key/value pairs.

This is the `FOR LOOP`:

```
dataObj = The Array Shown At Top of Post;
var val = dataObj;
var out = [];
var someObject = val[0];

for (var i in someObject) {
  if (someObject.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    out.push(someObject[i]);
  };
 };
```

The output from the for loop looks like this:

```
{,",C,8,_,2,3,5,5,5,0,",:,{,",l,i,s,t,i,n,g,",:,",a,u,t,,,C,8,_,2,3,5,5,5,0,_,2,2,0,1,4,4,6,5,0,6,5,4,",},,,",C,8,_,2,3,1,2,5,2,",:,{,",l,i,s,t,i,n,g,",:,",a,u,t,,,C,8,_,2,3,1,2,5,2,_,2,2,0,1,4,4,6,5,0,6,5,4,",},}
```

I'm wondering if the array got converted to a string, and is no longer recognized as an array, but just a string of characters.  But I don't know enough about this to know what is going on.  How do I get the `value` out for the `key` named `listing`?

Is this now just a string rather than an array?  Do I need to convert it back to something else?  JSON?  I've tried using different JavaScript array methods on the array, and nothing seems to return what it should if the data was an array.

Comment: `{"C8_235550": {"listing":"aut,C8_235550_220144650654"}, "C8_231252":
{"listing":"aut,C8_231252_220144650654"}}`
this is object not array..

Comment: Seems like you're getting JSON, try: `var someObject = JSON.parse(val);`

Comment: When I use: `var someObject = JSON.parse(val);` it returns `[object Object]` with `console.log(someObject);`.  But, if I check the length:  `var a = someObject.length;`, `console.log(a);` `undefined` is returned.  So JSON.parse(myData) does create an object, I guess, but it seems that something is still wrong.

Comment: The `JSON.parse(objString)` works, I just hadn't figured out how to use the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a way to get the elements out of your json string

as stated in the other answers, you should make it an obect again and get its keys and values.

```
function demo(){
  var string='{"C8_235550":{"listing":"aut,C8_235550_220144650654"},"C8_231252":{"listing":"aut,C8_231252_220144650654"}}';
  var ob = JSON.parse(string);
  for(var propertyName in ob) {
     Logger.log('first level key = '+propertyName);
  Logger.log('fisrt level values = '+JSON.stringify(ob[propertyName]));
    for(var subPropertyName in ob[propertyName]){
  Logger.log('second level values = '+ob[propertyName][subPropertyName]);
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an object, not an array. What you need to do is, use the

```
Object.keys()
```

method and obtain a list of keys which is the field names in that object. Then you could use a simple for loop to iterate over the keys and do whatever you need to do.

Comment: I'm getting the error: `[object Object] has no method 'keys'`

Comment: All I needed to do was this:

`Object.keys(myArryObject)`

That returns all the keys.